# Lohnsteuerbescheinigung - income tax certiicate

Tags: privacy, tax-law, germany

I currently live and work in Germany and I would like to apply for a tax return.

I have asked for help on a forum (in doing the paperwork) and one person wrote to me that she can help me out for a fee of 50 euros.

She asked me to send her my Lohnsteuerbescheinigung. Is it safe to send this document to a third party?

I have never met this person before, but the document does not appear to require strong security.

Answer (score 2):

`Lohnsteuerbescheinigung` contains really many sensitive informations about you, and to share with someone you don't know in the internet, isn't a good idea, as you don't really know if this person will really help you in the end, or just needs your informations for some illegal things...
I suggest for you to search a `Steuerberater`, because that is his work, and then you are 100% sure. For my case I did the same and it costed around 75euro (to pay 25euro more and to be sure is better I guess).